# Nodejs: single AWS instance or one per request

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, instance, multiple-instances

Should I create one global (in module) for AWS instance or create new instance on every request.

Single instance

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const S3 = new AWS.S3({});

app.use('/sign-s3', function(req, res) {
  // Do something
});
```

Multiple instance

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

app.use('/sign-s3', function(req, res) {
  const S3 = new AWS.S3({});
  // Do something
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason I can think of to create a new instance per request is if you needed to have different config values per request(such as credentials, region, etc.) Other than that I think it would be best to only create one instance.

Comment: Agreed, but all other tutorial create new instance every request So I just wonder why?

Comment: Hmm, I can't be sure but it seems like I've mostly noticed examples using one instance. For example you can see they ony use one in this S3/Lambda example http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html